# rx subject onNext() without parameter typescript

Tags: rxjs

Im using an observable to set a value in a different component. So in my `NavigationComponent` I have:

```
import toggleAside$ = SomeService.toggleAside$;

public toggleAdditionalInformation() {
    toggleAside$.onNext(false);
}
```

And in the other component I have:

```
export const toggleAside$ = new Rx.Subject();

public showAside: boolean;

private toggleAsideView(): void {
    toggleAside$.subscribe(() => {
        this.showAside = !this.showAside;
    });
}
```

I have a button the calls the `toggleAdditionalinformation()` function. This will create a stream with a false boolean value. In my other component I subscribe to the `toggleAside$` stream. When something happens it will change the class propperty `showAside`. My code works as I want. But the value in the `onNext()` is not being used for anything. But it requires 1 parameter.

So am I abusing the `onNext()` function for this or is there a different solution with the parameters? An empy null object or something?

I'm using rx-lite Release 4.0.8

Comment: You should say what version of rxjs you're using, especially when you're using a pretty old version. In newer rxjs versions you can just call `subject$.next()` without providing a parameter.

Comment: Rx-lite Release 4.0.8 is what we're currently using. Maybe I can upgrade :) At the moment I'm using a `null` value but that's not ideal. Thank you for the suggestion.